# (ckeditor) How change size of ckeditor's toolbar?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ckeditor

For some time I'm using ckeditor(ruby version) for simple editing posts but recently it started to look wrong:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/otHS0.png

As you see, the toolbar is shorter than the block of editing text and in the empty place came the word 'content'. How do you think, what's the problem?

In addition, here is the code where I call ckeditor:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :content %>
  <%= f.cktext_area :content,  :ckeditor => {:language => 'en' } %>
  <%= errors_for @page, 'content' %>
</div>
```

Comment: Your page's styles are breaking CKEditor. Try to debug this with one of DOM inspectors.

Comment: Thanks, found out that just <br/> tag was missing.